# I consider to modify my Wifi router Getnet GR-724W with OpenWrt to work with channel 14

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

In Europe, we are allowed to use WiFi channels up to 13. I didn't find anything that works on 2484 GHz (channel 14) in Europe.This channel is allowed in Japan.

I considered modifying my Getnet GR-724W WiFi router with OpenWRT to work with channel 14.

Why do I want to do that? 
I am only one using channel 13 (2472 GHz) and two of my neighbors are using channel 11 (they limit each other to 20 MHz).
Therefore, if I move one channel, I theoretically can use the full 40 MHz of the 802.11n network.

Any suggestion on the frequency use in Europe or why not to do that?

http://web.archive.org/web/20130720202154/http://smorgasbord.gavagai.nl/tags/openwrt/

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory

Comment: If you want to be 3 channels away from 11, why not use 8?

Comment: All the channels below have higher use - ch.11 2u,ch.6,9 1u, ch.1 2u

Comment: If you are in Europe you should not be using channel 14.  That channel is only allowed in Japan. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_Concerns)

Comment: Channels need to be spaced 4 apart (3 in between) to not interfere (except for 14 because it has an extra gap below it). If channels 12 or 13 are in use by your neighbors then you'll still get interference on 14. Unless you only want fast but short range communications, then focus on being being 4 channels away for best performance. 14 only legally allows legacy 801.11b speeds anyway. You'll also have quite a time getting clients to even see 14 in a scan.